# I tried to test the login with postman but there's an error

Tags: javascript, express, authentication, routes, postman

I developed the login router in the backend and I test it in Postman and it shows me this error
[image]

this is the code for login route :

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user =await User.findOne({email:req.body.email})
    if(!user){
      return res 
      .status(200)
      .send({message:"User does not exist",success:false})
    }
    const isMatch=await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,user.password);
    if(!isMatch){
      return res
      .status(200)
      .send({message:"Password is incorrect ",success:false})
    }
    else {
      const token=jwt.sign({id:user._id},process.env.JWT_SECRET,{
        expiresIn:"1d"
      })
    }
    if(user &&isMatch) {
          res.status(200).send({message:"Login successful",success:true,token,data:token});

    }
  } catch (error) {
    res
    .status(500)
    .send({message:"Error logging in ",success:false,error})

  }
});
```

Comment: Have you made a user with the credentials you put in Postman in your database?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a token variable in a local scope in else clauses, it can not be reached from sending response scope. try:

```
try {
    const user =await User.findOne({email:req.body.email})
    if(!user){
      return res 
      .status(200)
      .send({message:"User does not exist",success:false})
    }
    const isMatch=await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,user.password);
    if(!isMatch){
      return res
      .status(200)
      .send({message:"Password is incorrect ",success:false})
    }
    else {
      const token= jwt.sign({id:user._id},process.env.JWT_SECRET,{
        expiresIn:"1d"
      })
     
      res.status(200).send({message:"Login successful",success:true,token,data:token});
    }
 
  } catch (error) {
    res
    .status(500)
    .send({message:"Error logging in ",success:false,error})

  }
```